# How to take the output of one model as the input of another one with Tensorflow r-1.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have defined two classes of models, `x` and `y`.

```
class x():
    def __init__(self, x_inp1, x_inp2):
        # do sth...

    def step(self, session, encoder_inputs):
        input_feed = {}
        for l in range(encoder_size):
             input_feed[self.encoder_inputs[l].name] = encoder_inputs[l]
        ...
        output_feed = [x_output]
        return session.run(x_output)

class y():
    def __init__(self, y_inp1, y_inp2):
        # do sth...

    def step(self, encoder_inputs):
        input_feed = {}
        for l in range(encoder_size):
             input_feed[self.encoder_inputs[l].name] = encoder_inputs[l]
        ...
```

They have quite similar functions. And then I define another class to group them up.

```
class gp():
    def __init__(self, x_inp1, x_inp2, y_inp1, y_inp2):
        with tf.variable_scope('x'):
              self.x_model = x(x_inp1, x_inp2)
        with tf.variable_scope('y'):
              self.y_model = y(y_inp1, y_inp2)
    def step(self, session, encoder_inputs):
        x_output = self.x_model.step(session, encoder_inputs)
        y_output = self.y_model.step(session, x_output)
        ...
```

Please notice that the `y_model` takes the output of `x_model` as input. And I run the `gp()` in the `main` function:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     gp_m = gp(x_inp1, x_inp2, y_inp1, y_inp2)
     gp_m.step(sess, x_inp1, x_inp2, y_inp1, y_inp2)
```

And after running  `x_output = self.x_model.step(encoder_inputs)` and begin to do `y_output = self.y_model.step(x_output)`, I got such an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x/encoder0' with dtype int32
 [[Node: x/encoder0 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Please notice this error points to the `x_model` even the step function of it has been finished. I wonder how can I use the output of `x_model` as the input of `y_model` without any error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should defer the calls to `session.run` to be outside the `step` functions. The problem here is that trying to run Y triggers X because they are connected in the graph.

Instead, it might be better to fully separate your graph build and graph run stages of your program, so you know what placeholders to provide when.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am sorry that I am still a little confused. I should defer the calls to `session.run` to be outside WHICH `step` functions? 
And could you please tell me how to fully separate the graph? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: build the graph (i.e. call most tf functions) in one place, return the tensors you want to run, and call session.run in another place. To see a good way to structure your code try looking at tf.estimator.Estimator